# Spark notebook worksheets not saved with docker

Tags: scala, spark-notebook

When I start a spark-notebook using docker and create a new worksheet. The next time I start it, the worksheet isn't there.

Here's the command:

```
docker run -v /Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot/:/mnt -p 9000:9000 andypetrella/spark-notebook:0.2.0-spark-1.2.0-hadoop-1.0.4
```

Here's the warnings / info:

```
15/02/09 08:38:12 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://Remote@127.0.0.1:41602]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:41602
15/02/09 08:38:12 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef: Message [akka.remote.RemoteWatcher$Heartbeat$] from Actor[akka://NotebookServer/system/remote-watcher#-457307005] to Actor[akka://NotebookServer/deadLetters] was not delivered. [8] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Is this a misconfiguration issue or something else?

**Edit:**

So this problem has a few aspects to it.

1. When the running docker container is closed using ctrl-c, it actually still exists. When I run it anew with the command above, it starts a separate new container that doesn't have the newly created notebook.

This can be mitigated by looking at the list of running containers using `docker ps`, finding the running one and attaching to it using `docker attach process_id`. The data will still be present.

2. Using a mounted volume to store the notebooks to leads to a permissions issue. The directory mounted within the container only has owner write permissions, where the owner is user *1000*. The spark-notebook is run as the user *daemon* (user id *1*).

This is a long thread about this issue [on github,](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581), but no clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile will continue evolving but now at least we can backup our notebooks oustide the docker container.

This will do the trick:

`docker run --rm -v /Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot:/opt/docker/notebooks/ext -p 9000:9000 andypetrella/spark-notebook:0.6.0-scala-2.10.4-spark-1.4.1-hadoop-2.6.0`

So that the folder `Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot` will contain all notebooks in the `ext` folder in the spark-notebook listing.

That means that:

- all notebooks in `Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot` will be visible in the `ext` folder
- all newly created notebooks **in** the `ext` folder will be available on the host folder `Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot`.

Of course you could also have used:

`docker run --rm -v /Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot:/opt/docker/notebooks -p 9000:9000 andypetrella/spark-notebook:0.6.0-scala-2.10.4-spark-1.4.1-hadoop-2.6.0`

Which will discard all default notebooks and only show the content of `/Users/pkerp/projects/chairliftplot`. However, this way **all** newly created notebooks will be available in the host, no matter the folder where they have been created